# Email not received whereas shown as sent under gmail domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses, mail-server

Using rails stack and gmail as domain for email, i can see my mails under sent by email id whereas the mails are actually not received at my receipient's end. How do i proceed to solve this issue ?
Things i have done checked:

1) email limit under my amazon SES is way beyond the number of mails i send

2) i can see the mails under the default sender email id with cc and sent to marked correctly

```
class ReportsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: 'bot@xyz.in',reply_to: 'abc@xyz.in'


  def weekly_performance_email(sorted_centre_array, rank_diff, environment, hide_delta_column)

    @url  = "http://accounts.peerlearning.com";@centre_data = sorted_centre_array;@rank_diff = rank_diff;@from_date = (Time.now - 1.week).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    @to_date =  Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y");@hide_delta_column = hide_delta_column
    attachments.inline['upside.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/upside.png'));attachments.inline['downside.png'] = File.read(`Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/downside.png')); email_subj = '[Weekly Summary] Centre In-class Health Info'`
    if environment == EmailWorker::STAGING_ONLY
     mailto = "abc+MAILERTEST@xyz.in"
     email_subj = "MAILERTEST " + email_subj
     ccmailto = ""
    else
      mailto = ["pa@xyz.in","pm@xyz.in","efficacy@xyz.in"]
      ccmailto = ["tech+MAILERS@xyz.in"]
    end
    mail(to: mailto ,cc: ccmailto ,bcc: "bot@xyz.in",subject: email_subj)
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be running in sandbox mode.
In that case even the recipient id needs to be verified